# how to keep html string in var

Tags: ios, swift

I have such string:

```
    <p>
    —Â„Ó‰Ìˇ ‚ <strong>¿ÒÚ‡ÌÂ </strong>‚ ‡ÏÍ‡ı <strong>œÂÏËË &quot;ÃÛÁ-“¬ - 2015. √‡‚ËÚ‡ˆËˇ&quot;</strong> ÔÓ¯Î‡ ÒÓˆË‡Î¸Ì‡ˇ ‡ÍˆËˇ <strong>&quot;Ã˚ Á‡ ËÌÍÎ˛ÁË‚ÌÓÂ Ó·˘ÂÒÚ‚Ó!&quot;</strong>. <a href="http://dixinews.kz/articles/3297" target="_blank">œÎ‡ÌËÓ‚‡ÎÓÒ¸</a>, ˜ÚÓ Ô‡ÍÚË˜ÂÒÍË Ó‰ÌÓ‚ÂÏÂÌÌÓ ÔÓ ‚ÒÂÏÛ „ÓÓ‰Û ·Û‰ÂÚ Ó„‡ÌËÁÓ‚‡ÌÓ <strong>12</strong> ÚÂÏ‡ÚË˜ÂÒÍËı ÔÎÓ˘‡‰ÓÍ, Ì‡ ÍÓÚÓ˚ı ·ÓÎÂÂ <strong>2000</strong> ‰ÂÚÂÈ-ÒËÓÚ, ‰ÂÚÂÈ Ò Ó„‡ÌË˜ÂÌÌ˚ÏË ‚ÓÁÏÓÊÌÓÒÚˇÏË, ËÁ Ï‡ÎÓÓ·ÂÒÔÂ˜ÂÌÌ˚ı Ë ÌÂ·Î‡„ÓÔÓÎÛ˜Ì˚ı ÒÂÏÂÈ ÔÓÎÛ˜‡Ú ‚ÓÁÏÓÊÌÓÒÚ¸ ‚ÒÚÂÚËÚ¸Òˇ ÒÓ Á‚ÂÁ‰‡ÏË Í‡Á‡ıÒÚ‡ÌÒÍÓÈ Ë ÓÒÒËÈÒÍÓÈ ˝ÒÚ‡‰˚.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="678" src="/uploads/files/9db80cff8a026bbd94ca0ce22d0f3899.jpg" width="960" /></p>
<p>
    »ÒÔÓÎÌËÚÂÎ¸Ì˚È ‰ËÂÍÚÓ ÙÓÌ‰‡ &quot;ƒ‡‡&quot; <strong>Ã‡‰ËÌ‡ ¡‡ÍËÂ‚‡</strong> ‡ÒÒÍ‡Á‡Î‡ <strong>Dixinews.kz</strong> Ó ÚÓÏ, Ì‡ÒÍÓÎ¸ÍÓ ‚‡ÊÌÓ ÔÓ‚Â‰ÂÌËÂ ÔÓ‰Ó·Ì˚ı ‡ÍˆËÈ:</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        &mdash; Ã˚ ÒÓ‚ÏÂÒÚÌÓ Ò ÃÛÁ-“¬ Ó„‡ÌËÁÓ‚‡ÎË ·ÓÎ¸¯Û˛ ‡ÍˆË˛ &quot;Ã˚ Á‡ ËÌÍÎ˛ÁË‚ÌÓÂ Ó·˘ÂÒÚ‚Ó!&quot; ‰Îˇ ÚÓ„Ó, ˜ÚÓ·˚ ÔÓÍ‡Á‡Ú¸ ‚ÓÁÏÓÊÌÓÒÚË Ë Ú‡Î‡ÌÚ˚ ‡ÁÎË˜Ì˚ı ‰ÂÚÂÈ. ’Ó˜ÂÚÒˇ ÔË‚ÎÂ˜¸ ‚ÌËÏ‡ÌËÂ Ó·˘ÂÒÚ‚‡ Í ÚÓÏÛ, ˜ÚÓ, ÌÂÒÏÓÚˇ Ì‡ ‡ÁÎË˜Ì˚Â ‚ÓÁÏÓÊÌÓÒÚË, ‚ÒÂ ‰ÂÚË ËÏÂ˛Ú Ô‡‚Ó Ì‡ ‡Á‚ËÚËÂ, Ó·‡ÁÓ‚‡ÌËÂ Ë Ú‚Ó˜ÂÒÚ‚Ó.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>
    »Á‚ÂÒÚÌ˚Â ÏÛÁ˚Í‡ÌÚ˚ ‰ÂÈÒÚ‚ËÚÂÎ¸ÌÓ ÔÓ‰‡ËÎË ‰ÂÚˇÏ ‚ ¿ÒÚ‡ÌÂ Ì‡ÒÚÓˇ˘ËÈ Ô‡Á‰ÌËÍ, ÔÓ‡‰Ó‚‡‚ ‚ÌËÏ‡ÌËÂÏ Ë Á‡·ÓÚÓÈ &mdash; ÚÂÏ, ˜ÂÏ ‚ÒÂ„‰‡ ÓÚÎË˜‡˛ÚÒˇ ‡ÍˆËË ·Î‡„ÓÚ‚ÓËÚÂÎ¸Ì˚ı ÙÓÌ‰Ó‚&nbsp;&quot;ƒ‡‡&quot; Ë &quot;¿ˇÎ‡&quot;. ÕÓ, Í ÒÓÊ‡ÎÂÌË˛, ÌÂ ‚ÒÂ Á‚ÂÁ‰˚ Ò ‰ÓÎÊÌ˚Ï ÔÓÌËÏ‡ÌËÂÏ ÓÚÌÂÒÎËÒ¸ Í Ò‚ÓÂÈ ÏËÒÒËË ‰ÂÎËÚ¸Òˇ Ò ‰ÂÚ¸ÏË Ë ÔÓÍÎÓÌÌËÍ‡ÏË Ò‚ÂÚÓÏ Ë ‡‰ÓÒÚ¸˛. —‚Ë‰ÂÚÂÎÂÏ ˝ÚÓ„Ó ÒÚ‡Î‡ ÊÛÌ‡ÎËÒÚÍ‡ <strong>Dixinews.kz</strong>.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/1bc6ac18dd2d6b9fc0be9ce79034f11b.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
    ÃÂÓÔËˇÚËÂ ÔÓ‰ Ì‡Á‚‡ÌËÂÏ <strong>&quot;Œ·˘ÂÌËÂ ·ÂÁ „‡ÌËˆ&quot;</strong> ÔÓ¯ÎÓ Ì‡ ÔÎÓ˘‡‰ÍÂ Û <strong>ƒ‚Óˆ‡ ¯ÍÓÎ¸ÌËÍÓ‚ ËÏ. ”ÚÂÏËÒÓ‚‡</strong>. ÕÂÒÏÓÚˇ Ì‡ ÒËÎ¸ÌÛ˛ Ê‡Û, ‰ÂÚË¯ÍË Ò <strong>10</strong> <strong>ÛÚ‡ </strong>Ì‡˜‡ÎË ÒÓ·Ë‡Ú¸Òˇ Ì‡ ÔÎÓ˘‡‰ÍÂ. — <strong>11</strong> Ì‡˜‡Î‡Ò¸ ÌÂ·ÓÎ¸¯‡ˇ ‡ÁÏËÌÍ‡ ÔÂÂ‰ „Î‡‚Ì˚Ï ÒÓ·˚ÚËÂÏ &mdash; ÙÎÂ¯ÏÓ·ÓÏ ÒÓ Á‚ÂÁ‰‡ÏË ÓÒÒËÈÒÍÓÈ ˝ÒÚ‡‰˚, Î˛·ËÏˆ‡ÏË Ú˚Òˇ˜ ÔÓ‰ÓÒÚÍÓ‚, „ÛÔÔ‡ÏË <strong>&quot;MBand&quot;</strong> Ë <strong>&quot;¬»¿ √‡&quot;</strong>.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/d975ddb6c9487b2014dd548fc73302c6.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
    “‡ÌˆÂ‚‡Î¸ÌÛ˛ ‡ÁÏËÌÍÛ ‰ÂÚË ‰ÂÎ‡ÎË ‚ÏÂÒÚÂ Ò ËÁ‚ÂÒÚÌ˚ÏË ‚ ÒÚÓÎËˆÂ Ú‡ÌˆÓ‡ÏË ÍÓÎÎÂÍÚË‚‡ <strong>&quot;AT-Stars&quot;</strong>.&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/1e7fd645c6ca64892b327b1f49edc18b.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
    Œ‰Ì‡ÍÓ ÓÊË‰‡ÌËÂ ÍÛÏËÓ‚, Ì‡‚ÂÌÓÂ, ÛÚÓÏÎˇÎÓ ‰ÂÚË¯ÂÍ Â˘Â ·ÓÎ¸¯Â, ˜ÂÏ Ô‡Îˇ˘ÂÂ ÒÓÎÌˆÂ. —ÚÓËÚ ÓÚÏÂÚËÚ¸, ˜ÚÓ Û‚Ë‰ÂÚ¸ Ë ÛÒÎ˚¯‡Ú¸ Ò‚ÓËı Î˛·ËÏˆÂ‚ ÒÓ·‡ÎËÒ¸ ÌÂ ÚÓÎ¸ÍÓ ‰ÂÚË, ÌÓ Ë ÓÙËˆË‡Î¸Ì˚È Ù‡Ì-ÍÎÛ· „ÛÔÔ˚ <strong>&quot;MBand&quot;</strong> ‚ ¿ÒÚ‡ÌÂ. ƒÂ‚Ó˜ÍË „ÓÏÍÓ Ë Ò ·ÓÎ¸¯ÓÈ ÓÚ‰‡˜ÂÈ ÔÂÎË Ò‚Ó˛ Î˛·ËÏÛ˛ (Ë Ì‡Ë·ÓÎÂÂ ËÁ‚ÂÒÚÌÛ˛ Û ÍÓÎÎÂÍÚË‚‡) ÔÂÒÌ˛ <strong>&quot;ŒÌ‡ ‚ÂÌÂÚÒˇ&quot;</strong>.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/e69f9dbd6123338875efce07a5d2fbb2.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
    Õ‡ÍÓÌÂˆ, ‚&nbsp;<strong>12:20</strong>&nbsp;Ì‡ÒÚ‡Î ÚÓÚ Ò‡Ï˚È ÍÛÎ¸ÏËÌ‡ˆËÓÌÌ˚È ÏÓÏÂÌÚ, ÍÓÚÓÓ„Ó ‚ÒÂ Ê‰‡ÎË &mdash; &quot;MBand&quot; Ë &quot;¬»¿ √‡&quot; ‚˚¯ÎË Í ‰ÂÚˇÏ. ¬˚¯ÎË Ë Û¯ÎË. ÕÂÚ, ÌÂ ÔÓ‰ÛÏ‡ÈÚÂ &mdash; Á‚ÂÁ‰˚ ÔÓÒÏÓÚÂÎË ÙÎÂ¯ÏÓ·, ÍÓÚÓ˚È ÔÓ‰„ÓÚÓ‚ËÎË ÒÎ‡·ÓÒÎ˚¯‡˘ËÂ ‰ÂÚË. «‡ÊË„‡ÚÂÎ¸Ì˚È Ú‡ÌÂˆ ÔÓ‰ ÔÂÒÌ˛ <strong>&quot;”Î˚·‡ÈÒˇ&quot;</strong> ·˚Î ÔÓÍ‡Á‡Ì Ò ËÒÔÓÎ¸ÁÓ‚‡ÌËÂÏ ÊÂÒÚÓ‚Ó„Ó ˇÁ˚Í‡, ˜ÚÓ·˚ ÒÍ‡Á‡Ú¸ &quot;Ã˚ Á‡ ËÌÍÎ˛ÁË‚ÌÓÂ Ó·˘ÂÒÚ‚Ó!&quot;. ÕÂÏÌÓ„Ó ÔÓ‰‚Ë„‡‚¯ËÒ¸ Ì‡ ÒˆÂÌÂ Ë ÔÓÒÌËÏ‡‚ ‚ÒÂ Ì‡ Í‡ÏÂÛ, Á‚ÂÁ‰˚ Û‰‡ÎËÎËÒ¸.&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/df3283f00317dac55c1ffe472d08f69e.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
     ÓÌÂ˜ÌÓ ÊÂ, ‰ÂÚË ÓÊË‰‡ÎË ‰Û„Ó„Ó &mdash; Ó·˘ÂÌËˇ, Ú‡ÌˆÂ‚, ÙÓÚÓ„‡ÙËÈ, ‰‡ Ë ËÒÔÓÎÌÂÌËˇ &quot;ŒÌ‡ ‚ÂÌÂÚÒˇ&quot;, ‚ ÍÓÌˆÂ ÍÓÌˆÓ‚. œÓÒÎÂ ÛıÓ‰‡ Á‚ÂÁ‰ ÒÓ ÒˆÂÌ˚ ÁËÚÂÎË Ì‡˜‡ÎË „Ó‚ÓËÚ¸, ˜ÚÓ ÏÛÁ˚Í‡ÌÚ˚ ÔÓÒÎÂ‰Û˛Ú ÔËÏÂÛ „ÂÓËÌË Ò‚ÓÂÈ ÔÂÒÌË Ë ‚ÒÂ-Ú‡ÍË ‚ÂÌÛÚÒˇ, ˜ÚÓ·˚ ÒÔÂÚ¸. ÕÓ ˝ÚÓ„Ó ÌÂ ÒÎÛ˜ËÎÓÒ¸.</p>
<p>
    ” ÒÎÛÊÂ·ÌÓ„Ó ‚˚ıÓ‰‡ Á‚ÂÁ‰ Ê‰‡Î ÙÛ„ÓÌ Ë ÎË˜Ì˚È ‡‚ÚÓÏÓ·ËÎ¸, ‡ Â˘Â ÔÓÍÎÓÌÌËÍË, ÍÓÚÓ˚Â ÏÂ˜Ú‡ÎË Ò‰ÂÎ‡Ú¸ Á‡‚ÂÚÌÓÂ ÒÂÎÙË Ò ÍÛÏË‡ÏË. ÕÂÒÍÓÎ¸ÍËÏ Ò˜‡ÒÚÎË‚˜ËÍ‡Ï ˝ÚÓ ‚ÒÂ-Ú‡ÍË Û‰‡ÎÓÒ¸.&nbsp;</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        &mdash; Ã˚ Ëı ÚÓÎ¸ÍÓ ˜ÛÚ¸-˜ÛÚ¸ Û‚Ë‰ÂÎË, ÒÚÓÎ¸ÍÓ Ê‰‡ÎË. ŒÌË ‰‡ÊÂ Ò Ù‡Ì‡Ú‡ÏË ÌÂ ÒÙÓÚÓ„‡ÙËÓ‚‡ÎËÒ¸. Œ‰Ì‡ ‰Â‚Ó˜Í‡ ÔÓÒÚÓ ‡Á˚‰‡Î‡Ò¸, ˜ÚÓ ÌÂ ÔÓÎÛ˜ËÎÓÒ¸ ÔÓÓ·˘‡Ú¸Òˇ Ò Ô‡ÌˇÏË ËÁ „ÛÔÔ˚, &mdash; Ê‡ÎÓ‚‡ÎËÒ¸ ‰Â‚Ó˜ÍË-Ù‡Ì‡ÚÍË.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>
    √ÛÔÔ‡ <strong>&quot;MBand&quot;</strong> Ë Ëı ÏÂÌÂ‰ÊÂ ÓÚÍ‡Á‡ÎËÒ¸ ÓÚ Í‡ÍËı-ÎË·Ó ÍÓÏÏÂÌÚ‡ËÂ‚.&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/e3eb851e61f6700e82b4b58c6937a0bd.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
    œÓÒÎÂ ‚ÒÂ„Ó Û‚Ë‰ÂÌÌÓ„Ó ÊÛÌ‡ÎËÒÚ<strong> Dixinews.kz</strong> ÓÚÔ‡‚ËÎ‡Ò¸ Ì‡ Â˘Â Ó‰ÌÛ ÔÎÓ˘‡‰ÍÛ &mdash; ‚<strong> ÃÂÊ‰ÛÌ‡Ó‰ÌÛ˛ ¯ÍÓÎÛ QSI</strong>, „‰Â ÔË ÔÓ‰‰ÂÊÍÂ ‘Â‰Â‡ˆËË ÙÛÚ·ÓÎ‡  ‡Á‡ıÒÚ‡Ì‡ ÒÓÒÚÓˇÎÒˇ Ï‡Ú˜ ÍÓÏ‡Ì‰˚ ÒÎ‡·ÓÒÎ˚¯‡˘Ëı ÔÓ‰ÓÒÚÍÓ‚ ÔÓÚË‚ ÍÓÏ‡Ì‰˚ Á‚ÂÁ‰ &mdash; „ÛÔÔ˚ <strong>&quot;RinGo&quot;</strong>, ÔÂ‚ˆÓ‚ Black Star Inc. <strong>Õ‡Ú‡Ì‡</strong> Ë<strong> ÃÓÚ‡</strong>, ‡ Ú‡ÍÊÂ <strong>ÕËÍËÚ˚ œÂÒÌˇÍÓ‚‡</strong>. –Â·ˇÚ‡ Ò Û‰Ó‚ÓÎ¸ÒÚ‚ËÂÏ ‚ÍÎ˛˜ËÎËÒ¸ ‚ Ë„Û Ë ÒÏÓ„ÎË Â‡·ËÎËÚËÓ‚‡Ú¸ ÓÒÒËÈÒÍËÈ ¯ÓÛ-·ËÁÌÂÒ ÔÓÒÎÂ ÔÂ‰˚‰Û˘Â„Ó ÏÂÓÔËˇÚËˇ.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" height="682" src="/uploads/files/a6ee4e7065b95f1ebd9c2e3938471f09.jpg" width="1024" /></p>
<p>
    ¬ Ï‡Ú˜Â ÍÓÏ‡Ì‰ Á‚ÂÁ‰ ÔÓË„‡Î‡ ÒÓ Ò˜ÂÚÓÏ <strong>3:1</strong>, ‡ ‰ÂÚË ÔÓÎÛ˜ËÎË ËÁ ÛÍ ‚ËˆÂ-ÔÂÁË‰ÂÌÚ‡ ‘‘  <strong>—ÂËÎ¸‰˚ ¡‡È¯‡ÍÓ‚‡</strong> ÔÓ·Â‰Ì˚È ÍÛ·ÓÍ.</p>
<p>
    œÓÒÎÂ Ï‡Ú˜‡<strong> Õ‡Ú‡Ì</strong>, ÍÓÚÓ˚È, ÍÒÚ‡ÚË, Ó‰ÓÏ ËÁ <strong>¿ÎÏ‡Ú˚</strong>, ÔÓ‰ÂÎËÎÒˇ Ò‚ÓËÏË Ó˘Û˘ÂÌËˇÏË Ò <strong>Dixinews.kz</strong>:</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        &mdash; ƒÎˇ ÏÂÌˇ Ó˜ÂÌ¸ ‚‡ÊÌÓ Û˜‡ÒÚËÂ ‚ Ú‡ÍËı ·Î‡„ÓÚ‚ÓËÚÂÎ¸Ì˚ı ÏÂÓÔËˇÚËˇı, Ï˚ ÔÓ‰‰ÂÊË‚‡ÂÏ Í‡Í ÏÓÊÂÏ &mdash; ÏÛÁ˚ÍÓÈ, Ó‰ÂÊ‰ÓÈ, ‰‡ÊÂ ÔÓÒÚÓ ‚ÌËÏ‡ÌËÂÏ. ¬ ¿ÒÚ‡ÌÂ ˇ ÌÂ ‚ ÔÂ‚˚È ‡Á, Ë ˝ÚÓÚ „ÓÓ‰ ıÓÓ¯Ó ÔÓ‰ıÓ‰ËÚ ‰Îˇ ÔÓ‚Â‰ÂÌËˇ œÂÏËË. ¬ÓÓ·˘Â,  ‡Á‡ıÒÚ‡Ì ‚ –ÓÒÒËË Ë ÒÚ‡Ì‡ı —Õ√ Ò˜ËÚ‡ÂÚÒˇ ÚÓÔÓ‚˚Ï „ÓÒÛ‰‡ÒÚ‚ÓÏ, Á‰ÂÒ¸ Ó˜ÂÌ¸ ÏÌÓ„Ó ÒˆÂÌ, ÔÎÓ˘‡‰ÓÍ ‰Îˇ ‚˚ÒÚÛÔÎÂÌËÈ. œÂÏËˇ ‚ ¿ÒÚ‡ÌÂ &mdash; ˝ÚÓ ÌÂÛ‰Ë‚ËÚÂÎ¸ÌÓ.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>
     ‡Í ÓÍ‡Á‡ÎÓÒ¸, <strong>ÕËÍËÚ‡ œÂÒÌˇÍÓ‚</strong> Ú‡ÍÊÂ ÌÂ ‚ÔÂ‚˚Â ‚ Ì‡¯ÂÈ ÒÚÓÎËˆÂ:</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        &mdash; ¬‡ÊÌÓ ÔÓ‚Ó‰ËÚ¸ ÔÓ‰Ó·Ì˚Â ÏÂÓÔËˇÚËˇ, ‚Â‰¸ ‰‡ËÚ¸ ÛÎ˚·ÍË &mdash; ˝ÚÓ „Î‡‚ÌÓÂ. ﬂ Ó˜ÂÌ¸ Î˛·Î˛ ¿ÒÚ‡ÌÛ, ÚÛÚ Û‰Ë‚ËÚÂÎ¸ÌÓ ÚÂÔÎÓ, Ó·˚˜ÌÓ Ó˜ÂÌ¸ ‚ÂÚÂÌÌÓ ·˚‚‡ÂÚ. ﬂ Ò˜ËÚ‡˛, Á‰ÓÓ‚Ó, ˜ÚÓ œÂÏËˇ ÔÓ‚Ó‰ËÚÒˇ ‚ ¿ÒÚ‡ÌÂ, Ì‡Ï ‚˚Âı‡Ú¸ ÍÛ‰‡-ÚÓ Ë ‚˚ÒÚÛÔËÚ¸ ‚ÒÂ„‰‡ ÔËˇÚÌÓ. ¿ÒÚ‡Ì‡ &mdash; Ó˜ÂÌ¸ Í‡ÒË‚˚È „ÓÓ‰, Ë œÂÏËˇ Á‰ÂÒ¸ ÓÚÎË˜ÌÓ ‚ÔËÒ˚‚‡ÂÚÒˇ.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>
    ŒÚÏÂÚËÏ, ˜ÚÓ ‚ÒÂ ‰ÂÚË, Û˜‡ÒÚÌËÍË ÒÓˆË‡Î¸ÌÓÈ ‡ÍˆËË <strong>‘ÓÌ‰‡ &quot;ƒ‡‡&quot;</strong>, Ú‡ÍÊÂ ·ÂÒÔÎ‡ÚÌÓ ÔËÏÛÚ Û˜‡ÒÚËÂ Ì‡ ÍÓÌˆÂÚÂ œÂÏËË &quot;ÃÛÁ-“¬ &mdash; 2015. √‡‚ËÚ‡ˆËˇ&quot; <strong>5 Ë˛Ìˇ</strong> Ì‡ <strong>&quot;¿ÒÚ‡Ì‡ ¿ÂÌÂ&quot;</strong>.</p>
```

I want to assign this to some var and decode it. The problem is that I cant assign it to var. I tried to put \ sign before " sign. However this doesnt work. How to keep such string in var?

Comment: What is the actual objective here? Perhaps there is a better way to go about accomplishing what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always save this HTML to a file in caches/documents directory or the bundle then load it in like:

```
let content = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

The quotation marks are going to be an issue to escape in code, you would need to manually escape them all, perhaps with a find-and-replace.

Comment: I did editing manually. So how can I convert that string using encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Comment: Paste the raw HTML into a file, load to string as posted above. Or if you manually escaped it yourself, you can convert it using the method on String/NSString called UTF8String.

    string.UTF8String()